# Hover animation makes initial animation rerun after mouse out

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an element with an animation started one time at the beegining and an animation running infinitly when hover.

When the mouse goes out, the infinite animation stop but the initial rerun, how can I prevent that ?

Here is an example, I don't want the kf-initial animation to rerun when mouse goes out.

Thanks !

```css
.foo {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  width: fit-content;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
    
  /* The initial animation */
  animation: kf-initial 2s;
}

.foo:hover {
  /* The infinite animation */
  animation: kf-hover 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes kf-initial {
  from {transform: scale(0.2)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes kf-hover {
  100% {transform: rotate(1turn)}
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the initial state animation to run again after you mouse out of the hover state and you want the element to return to its previous orientation. You will need to add a class to the foo element using JavaScript and add in CSS for that class that no longer allows that animation to run.

```js
const fooEl = document.querySelector(".foo");

fooEl.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  fooEl.classList.add("stopped");
})
```

```css
.foo {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  width: fit-content;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
    
  /* The initial animation */
  animation: kf-initial 2s;
}

.stopped {
  animation: none;
}

.foo:hover {
  /* The infinite animation */
  animation: kf-hover 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes kf-initial {
  from {transform: scale(0.2)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes kf-hover {
  100% {transform: rotate(1turn)}
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: Of course how did I not saw that. Thanks a lot for both of you, this is 2 nice solution for the issue !

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck, keep coding!

Answer (score 3):

This could be the solution. You currently have two animations that use the property `transform` altogether, what you need to do is separate them then the problem is easy peasy. I also add a paused/running state on hover for a little smoothness.

```css
.foo {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  width: fit-content;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  
  /* The infinite animation */
  animation: kf-hover 10s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.bar {
  /* The initial animation */
  animation: kf-initial 2s;
}

.foo:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes kf-initial {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.2)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes kf-hover {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="foo">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was expecting this kind of solution. This is a little bit inconveniant as I have now 2 div for the same content, only for this purpose.
So I will adopt it, but let the question open for know, in case some one has some magic solution ;)